# Are "more often than not" and "usually" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

I learned [a few posts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%20%22more%20often%20than%20not%22) about "more often than not" and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/more-often-than-not). I guess I understand its meaning, that is, "usually".

I went through some examples in those reference and don't see the difference if I substitute "usually" for "more often than not" in them.

So, are "more often than not" and "usually" interchangeable in any cases? Is it a matter of being formal/informal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*More often than not* means *more than 50% of the time* (it is the case more often than it isn't the case). *Usually* could be *almost always.* So, no, they don't mean exactly the same.